# Make jQuery works for element created with "insertAfter" etc

Tags: jquery

I have some elements like `<a class='link'>click</a>` which are created after clicking on another div ...
Is there any chance to make jQuery works for `<a class='link'>click</a>` ?

For now I'm forced to use `<a onclick='func()' class='link'>click</a>` ... and it's not possible to make something like `alert($(this).html())` (which must pop-up the text "click").

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `live()` method which will handle events for dynamically added elements.

```
$('a.link').live('click', function() {
    alert( $(this).html() );
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/live/

Or you could just bind the click like normal when you create them.

```
$('<a class="link">click</a>').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).html() );
}).insertAfter(someselector);
```